# Excel, Need to reference the left column after using larger

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

I need to create a sheet on my work where one of the data it has is how many people you attended in a neinghorhood in a month (social service) then we need to contabilize this data to discover the top 10 most attended neighboorhods.

**What I did:**

First I use `cont.if` to discover how many attendances we had in every neighboorhood, that generates a sheet like that:

```
|--------------|--------------|
|Neighboorhood |Ocurrences    |
|--------------|--------------|
|N1            |12            |
|N2            |3             |
|N3            |15            |
|...           |...           |
|NX            |xx            |
|--------------|--------------|
```

etc...

But then I need to sort this data in other sheet (a report one) where it would automatically pick the 10 neighboorhoods with most ocurrences and automatically display this data in a table (as it will be used by people with little knowledge of office suit, so they would only need to put how many attendances they had and the table would do all the hard work automatically), I tried to use a formula like:

```
|-----------------------------------|--------------------|
|Most Ocurrences                    |                    |
|-----------------------------------|--------------------|
|=Larger(offset($O2:O$6,0,-1,1,1),1)|=Larger($O$2:$O$6,1)|
|=Larger(offset($O2:O$6,0,-1,1,1),2)|=Larger($O$2:$O$6,2)|
|...                                |...                 |
```

in hopes that it would show something like this:

```
|-----------------------------------|--------------------|
|Most Ocurrences                    |                    |
|-----------------------------------|--------------------|
|N3                                 |15                  |
|N1                                 |12                  |
|...                                |...                 |
```

but it ends in a error like that:

```
|-----------------------------------|--------------------|
|Most Ocurrences                    |                    |
|-----------------------------------|--------------------|
|#NUM!                              |15                  |
|#NUM!                              |12                  |
|...                                |...                 |
```

Because I believe the program is considering that I want to offset the values used on the formula, and not the result, so it tries to calculate the larger with the offset which uses number, but the cell to the left has text so the error. But what I need is to it to calculate the larger, then pick up the value of the cell left (or right if its easier) from it and display it too, is possible to do it without a macro?

Like:

**Column A2:** shows the value of the cell from the left of the largest value

**Column B2:** Find the largest value.

**Column A3:** shows the value of the cell from the left of the second largest value

**Column B3:** Find the second largest value. 
etc...

Is that possible? i don't want to use macros as the people who will deal with it don't will know how to run macros, neither that would be possible, as they only have libre office, while we have office.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So first lets get the numbers in order:

A slight change to your LARGE formula will make it Dragable:

```
=LARGE($O$2:$O$6,ROW(1:1))
```

This will make it so you do not need to hard code the sequence in each formula.

Next let's get the name:

```
=INDEX($N:$N,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($O$2:$O$6)/($O$2:$O$6=B2),COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)))
```

---

***EDIT***

For pre 2010 excel you will need to use this array formula:

```
=INDEX($N:$N,LARGE(IF($O$2:$O$6=B2,ROW($O$2:$O$6)),COUNTIF($B$2:B2,B2)))
```

As an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

---

This will return the neighborhood.  It will also ensure that if there is duplicate numbers in column B it will find the next.

It refers to the numbers returned in column B.

---

With your data on a sheet called `database`:

[image]

Comment: thanks! it works nicely for the first 2 results, then it just repeat the fist one, in this case NA is the one with the most, followed by NB, NC, ND, NE, it shows the ammount in C,D,E just fine but in the name it messes up, any idea why?


it apears like this:


|NA 4|

|NB 4|

|**NA** 3 (it would be NC)|
 
|**NA** 2 (it would be ND)|
 
|**NA** 1 (it would be NE)|

Comment: @Kaikidan it works for me, without issue.  If your data has errors then it will not work.

Comment: Wanna take a look in what i did wrong? i uploaded it on docs https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14tcb2haXZas3E_FFL14qtoopOKa1hxOH0-UgRiImdAY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you using Google sheets?

Comment: Again I have no problems with the formula.  Are you dragging it down to fill?

Comment: Then I cannot imagine the issue, as I cannot replicate it.  Copy and paste the formula in A6 into the comments here. I want to spot check it.

Comment: =INDEX(database.D:D;AGGREGATE(15;6;ROW(database.E:E)/(database.E:E=B6);COUNTIF($B$2:B6;B6))) i dragged from A1. it displays as #DIV/0

Comment: is it really `database.D:D` I did not think the `!` changed with local settings, other than that I cannot see anything wrong with the formula and why it will not give the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks! i will see if its some local setting (my machine is PT-BR) but just having the formula is helpfull enough, i will try to fix it here.

Comment: Found the problem! My version in work is Excel 2007 it doens't have the Aggregate option.

Comment: Then the error you should have gotten was `#NAME` not `#DIV/0`.

Comment: It finally worked! it was the aggregate function, i used the pré-2010 excel formula you posted and it worked nicely. Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: @Kaikidan Please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
=index($n2:n$6, match(large($o2:o$6, row(1:1)), $o2:o$6, 0))
```

To avoid duplicates you need to use COUNTIF but the destination (where you are putting the formula) must be known.